# Applying xslt to xml with a namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

I know that there are multiple answered questions on this subject already and I have read several of them and attempted to implement the suggestions but so far without success.

I am trying to create an xsl to apply to an xml. The xml is from a P2 camera card and has a namespace declaration.

I have added a namespace declaration to my xsl but I still don't appear to be able to select the elements that I want.

My xsl looks like this (the current iteration of it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:schemas-Professional-Plug-in:P2:ClipMetadata:v3.1">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/xsi:P2Main">

<xsl:element name="clip">
  <video>
  <codec>
    <xsl:value-of select="xsi:ClipContent/xsi:EssenceList/xsi:Video/xsi:Codec" />
    </codec>
    <byteoffset>
    <xsl:value-of select="/xsi:P2Main/xsi:ClipContent/xsi:EssenceList/xsi:Video/xsi:VideoIndex/xsi:StartByteOffset" />
    </byteoffset>
    <bytecount>
    <xsl:value-of select="//xsi:Video/xsi:VideoIndex/xsi:DataSize" />
    </bytecount>
     <starttimecode>
     <xsl:value-of select="//xsi:Video/xsi:StartTimeCode" />
      </starttimecode>
      <framerate>
     <xsl:value-of select="//xsi:Video/xsi:FrameRate" /> 
      </framerate>
    </video>
  </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the xml I am trying to transform looks like this (not the complete file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<P2Main xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:schemas-Professional-Plug-in:P2:ClipMetadata:v3.1">
  <ClipContent>
    <ClipName>0002CC</ClipName>
    <GlobalClipID>060A2B340101010501010D43130000005E4D83E9398105D4008045826CF62010</GlobalClipID>
    <Duration>220</Duration>
    <EditUnit>1001/24000</EditUnit>
    <EssenceList>
      <Video ValidAudioFlag="false">
        <VideoFormat>MXF</VideoFormat>
        <Codec Class="100">AVC-I_1080/29.97p</Codec>
        <FrameRate>23.98p</FrameRate>
        <StartTimecode>08:24:36:04</StartTimecode>
        <StartBinaryGroup>A30F24C3</StartBinaryGroup>
        <AspectRatio>16:9</AspectRatio>
        <VideoIndex>
          <StartByteOffset>32768</StartByteOffset>
          <DataSize>103854592</DataSize>
        </VideoIndex>
      </Video>
      <Audio>
        <AudioFormat>MXF</AudioFormat>
        <SamplingRate>48000</SamplingRate>
        <BitsPerSample>16</BitsPerSample>
        <AudioIndex>
          <StartByteOffset>32768</StartByteOffset>
          <DataSize>880880</DataSize>
        </AudioIndex>
      </Audio>
      <Audio>
        <AudioFormat>MXF</AudioFormat>
        <SamplingRate>48000</SamplingRate>
        <BitsPerSample>16</BitsPerSample>
        <AudioIndex>
          <StartByteOffset>32768</StartByteOffset>
          <DataSize>880880</DataSize>
        </AudioIndex>
      </Audio>
```

However, I never seem to be able to select the nodes that I want, either resulting in an empty file with just my new elements in it, or (with the above iteration) a file that includes all of the values but not of the elements themselves.

I *have* to use xsl v1.0 and I am by no means an expert of xsl (which probably shows) so I'm not sure whether the issue is down to my Xpath declarations, the namespace or a combination of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the right namespace. `xsi` is the prefix for the attributes aimed at attaching an XML schema to your document. Your document is bound to the namespace with the `urn:schemas-Professional-Plug-in:P2:ClipMetadata:v3.1` URI.

You need to modify your stylesheet like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:P2="urn:schemas-Professional-Plug-in:P2:ClipMetadata:v3.1">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/P2:P2Main">

  <xsl:element name="clip">
    <video>
      <codec>
        <xsl:value-of select="P2:ClipContent/P2:EssenceList/P2:Video/P2:Codec" />
    </codec>
    <byteoffset>
    <xsl:value-of select="/P2:P2Main/P2:ClipContent/P2:EssenceList/P2:Video/P2:VideoIndex/P2:StartByteOffset" />
    </byteoffset>
    <bytecount>
    <xsl:value-of select="//P2:Video/P2:VideoIndex/xsi:DataSize" />
    </bytecount>
     <starttimecode>
     <xsl:value-of select="//P2:Video/P2:StartTimeCode" />
      </starttimecode>
        <framerate>
          <xsl:value-of select="//P2:Video/P2:FrameRate" /> 
        </framerate>
      </video>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you're using XSL-T 1.0, you need to prefix all the elements in the paths in `@select` or `@match` attributes like above.

With XSL-T 2.0 or higher, you could you use the `xpath-default-namespace` and won't need to prefix everything, e.g. by using this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xpath-default-namespace="urn:schemas-Professional-Plug-in:P2:ClipMetadata:v3.1">

  <xsl:template match="/P2Main">
     ...
     <xsl:value-of select="ClipContent/EssenceList/Video/Codec" />
     ...
```

etc.